# Don't know why this error occurs, on Mutable Live data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

[image: ndr]

Getting error when space is not available between LiveData = _darkMode

Does anyone know why this is occurring or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

You need a space before the equal sign:

```
val darkMode: LiveData<Boolean> = _darkMode
```